# Caching design patterns for Web Application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, caching, memcached

we are using memcache for a ASP.NET MVC3 application.

I want to know recommended design patterns or libraries which people use to manage data, because there will be so many keys that will get generated that it might be little painful to manage then and figure out which data is getting dirty and how to refresh the data so that we have a clean copy of data in our cache and our data integrity is there and we don't get into dirty cache.

Thanks
Saarthak

Comment: How many data is in cache? What is average size of the cache? How many read/write transactions?

Comment: I don't exactly know, but it will surely touch few 100MBs. We have not  implemented cache yet but we want to do so by following an industry recommended practice. We just did a small implementation to get have a hang of Memcache. Found a nice article on this - http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/articles/domain-objects-caching-pattern.html

Likewise, wanted to know if there are other patterns or practices being followed. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I really get your question, but this is the way I use to manage memcached access and keys
*First Id like to say that this might not be the best way as I am new to caching*

```
public class City { String name; }

public interface CityRepository
{
    City GetCityById(Int32 id);
}

public class SqlCityRepository : CityRepository
{
    public City GetCityById(Int32 id)
    {
        //SQL CODE

        return null;
    }
}

public class MemcachedRepository : CityRepository
{
    public CityRepository repository { get; set; }

    public MemcachedRepository(CityRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public City GetCityById(Int32 id)
    {
        //IF(CHECK_IF_KEY_IS_PRESENT_AT_MEMCACHED)
        //  RETURN CACHED_VALUE(KEY);
        //ELSE
            var result = this.repository.GetCityById(id);
            //ADD result TO CACHED ITEMS
            return result;
    }
}
```

And this is how I generate my keys

```
CLASSNAME + METHODNAME + PARAMS
```

This way I end up caching the method resultd

Comment: on top of these you should implement a cache expiration policy, which you can use datetime as the cache expiration, if the item in the cache are older than the datetime difference (interval). go to database and place it in the cache otherwise. get it from the cache.

Comment: Youre right! And if you wanna unit test your cache expiration policy you may implement AmbientContext pattern instead of strictly use DateTime implementation!!! It works nice for my HW application..!

Comment: Renota, your answer is on the lines of the solution that I am looking for. But this still is quite a basic implementation. Have a look at this article - http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/articles/domain-objects-caching-pattern.html 

This guy suggests a nicer way to doing things. So, like that I am looking for a solution that may have been widely used.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great serieas of articles about caching at mvc 3: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Cache-Exploration-in-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Part-1.aspx

Comment: thanks for sharing 0lukasz0 but this isn't what I am looking for.